# PHP escaping \14 character in file paths

Tags: php, string, escaping

I know there're plenty of topics regarding escaping characters but I just can't find the solution for my problem.

It's very easy. This is string I have:

```
$path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\14409238.jpg";
```

Howver, no matter how many escaping techniques I use, I can't manage to display the correct path without destroying it. In all cases the \14 will be replaced with

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktopd09238.jpg
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `$path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\14409238.jpg";`

Comment: Or you can use single quotes. PHP will use it as literal string.

Comment: @Rizier123 that is the right answer, should not be in the comments.

Comment: Or just use `/` instead.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I had forgotten to mention that $path is the output I get, I have no influence on it whatsoever. I have to deal with what it gives me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use backslashes in PHP for windows paths. It's smart enough to convert for you:

```
$path = "c:/users/me/desktop/...";
```

Using backslashes runs into the exact problem you have - backslashing certain characters turns them into metacharacters, not regular characters.

Answer (score 3):

try to change, the Physical path to access the image, stored on Desktop can be written as,

```
$path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\14409238.jpg";
```

to

```
$path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\14409238.jpg";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I had forgotten that I do not have control over what $path gives me. And well, it does give me those annoying backslashes.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the situation entirely, PHP under Windows allows you to submit paths with the backslash

c://Users/Me/Desktop/file.jpg

This also avoids interoperability headaches when a script must run within .nix and Windows.

Comment: It's not just PHP that allows it. This is part of Windows itself.